# Is the use of words "institute" and "college" together in naming an institution right?

Tags: word-usage

Is it right to use the words "institute" and "college" in naming an educational institution namely "Institute of Public Policy & Leadership College"? It is an affiliated institution/college under a university.

It seems to me that one word is enough and the other is redundant.

Comment: Are you creating this name yourself or are you trying to understand someone else's name? If the former, [ell.se] is probably a better place to ask this. If the latter, what is the source? I'd say the problem is not redundancy of meaning, but overloading the grammar - either The place of America" or "America's Place", not "The Place of America's Place".

Comment: It is the latter: someone else's name.

Comment: +1 for a nicely worded new question ! Do you have a web-link of this College ? In case, we want to show that there are 2 Distinct Entities here, we may have to use this format.

Comment: @rajankila Since this is a name you found somewhere, can you give the source? (a link to a website where this is used)

Comment: No results found for "Institute of Public Policy & Leadership College," but it sure looks redundant.

Comment: Local naming conventions vary all over the lot. You can never tell how an official name is usually pronounced when you see it written, and it's usually just a bunch of nouns with occasional adjectives in some order, with the parsing taken for granted locally. So it may make sense in one place and not in another.

Comment: Please do not cross post. Thanks. **Leadership and Public Policy Institute**

Comment: I have come across cases where Multiple Units co-exist : Eg "X Hospital & Medical College" , "Y Diagnostic Center and Clinic" , "Z Institute & Political Consultancy"

Comment: This is the sentence, "In the first stage, KILA will start Institute of Public Policy and Leadership PG College.... " in the news item ( the foundation stone of it was laid last day) at the link https://www.newindianexpress.com/states/kerala/2022/jun/06/leadership-crash-course-for-politicians-public-figures-bykila-2462179.html

Answer (score 2):

This title probably means:

> Institute of Public Policy
>
> and
>
> Leadership College

If not, yes I agree that having these two words together in the same title is redunant.

Comment: +1 , Yes, There may be 2 Distinct Entities here : "Institute" == "organization to promote art, science" && "College" == "organization catering higher education" ....

Comment: Chances are that there are that, at one level of organisational hierarchy, there are two entities here, which, at the next higher level, constitute one entity.